# comparing objects in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get some data payload from a users API request(from API body) usually given in a JSON format.
It is stored as a Dictionary in my python code.

```
"Data":{
      "Ready Date":"2020-01-31T12:00:00",
      "Ready Time":"2020-01-31T12:00:00",
      "Delivery Date":"2020-02-15T12:00:00",
      "Service Level":"EC",
      "Close Time":"2020-01-31T17:00:00"}
```

I want to validate the given fields.
If a user does not give "Ready Date", it should say Ready Date missing and check for each object within that JSON and say if something is missing

My code : I am storing all the dictionary keys in a array like :

```
a = ["Ready Date","Ready Time","DeliveryDate","Service Level","Close Time"]
```

My logic

```
for value in data:
    if value not in a:
        print("value Missing" : Value)
    else:
        print("All values are entered")
```

Result :
if I gave all the values in the dictionary and the list same,

```
My results prints :
All values are entered
All values are entered
All values are entered
```

if i remove any value from the the dictionary and check the condition, I get the following print result

```
value missing : Ready Date
All values are entered
All values are entered
```

I need to avoid the looping and only print it once

Comment: You can directly check `key not in my_dict`. You don't need a separate list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to ask a question without first providing proof you tried (though you didn't ask a question you gave a task), but here's the answer:

```py
data = {
      "Ready Date":"2020-01-31T12:00:00",
      "Ready Time":"2020-01-31T12:00:00",
      "Delivery Date":"2020-02-15T12:00:00",
      "Service Level":"EC",
      "Close Time":"2020-01-31T17:00:00"}
a = ["Ready Date","Ready Time","DeliveryDate","Service Level","Close Time"]

missing = [field for field in a if field not in data]

if len(missing) == 0:
    print("All values are entered")
else:
    [print(f"Missing value: {field}") for field in missing]
```

Comment: I tried with a sample from my end
thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}

thisarray = ["model","year"]

for i in thisdict:
    if i not in thisarray:
        print(i + " is missing")
    else:
        print("all fields entered") 

Output : 
brand is missing
all fields entered
all fields entered

Comment: The `if`/`else` can be condensed into one line with a ternary operator and a walrus operator.

Comment: @AshisAkshantal what do you mean?

Comment: The code you sent won't work as planned: if the `else` is on the same line as the `if`, statement then `"all fields entered"` will print at every key that's there, if it's in the same line as the `for` loop then `"all fields entered"` will print no matter what.

Comment: Yes, I was not able to formulate the looping part. The print statement execute multiple times. I tried your solution it works.

Comment: Do you want me to edit the code to make it less lines?  (It will be less code but a little harder to read,)

Comment: don't use list comprehensions for side-effects, `[print(f"Missing value: {field}") for field in missing]` list comprehensions are for *making lists*

Comment: I tested the code with a 5 item list using `timeit.Timer()` and `timeit.timeit()` and list comprehension does the task faster.  List comprehension: 1.1325898999999993.  For loop: 1.5533800999999983.  (I dropped the `print()` statement in the time test as the time it takes to print is uniform.)

Comment: ` {'data': {'shipmentInfo': {'Ready Date', 'Ready Time', 'Delivery Date', 'Service Level'}}} `
I tried the same logic to fetch the keys from the above dictionary in python, but it does not fetch any keys within 'data'. 

check_list = ["data", "shipmentInfo", "Ready Date","Ready Time","Delivery Date","Service Level"]
missing = [field for field in x if field not in check_list]
if len(missing) == 0:

Comment: You need to access the data in that dict and assign it to `data`. `data = {'data': {'shipmentInfo': {'Ready Date', 'Ready Time', 'Delivery Date', 'Service Level'}}}['data']['shipmentInfo']`.